# how to call __next__ on iterators n times in python

Tags: python, iterator

if we have the following code:

```
s = "stackoverflow"
si = iter(s)
si.__next__() # Would return s
si.__next__() # Would return t
si.__next__() # Would return a
```

is there a way without using loops I can get `"a"` with a single call to `__next__()`. so basically I want to call `__next__()` three times and get the third value. (Note that an iterator must be used,I can't just use slicing)

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> si = iter(s)
>>> next(islice(si, 2, 3))
'a'
```